# Opening a file with a # in its path using the default application from Excel 2007

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, hyperlink, special-characters

I have a pdf file which is located at "D:\some\#folder\filename.pdf". And want to open it from an Excel worksheet by clicking on a hyperlink (or something similar).

Just creating a hyperlink does not work, because it fails at the `#` character. Instead of opening the pdf, the folder "D:\some\" is opened in Windows Explorer.

Changing the pathname (i.e. moving the file) is not an option, because a lot of other programs and scripts rely on its location. Replacing `#` with `%23` does not work ("File not found.").

I found an official [workaround](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/202261), but it only seems to work when referencing cells in other Excel files at "unsupported" locations, not other file types.

Creating a shortcut to the pdf and hyperlinking to the shortcut (as suggested in a [related answer](https://superuser.com/a/492819/191912)) works, but leads to annoying security alerts which I would like to avoid.

What else can I do to emulate hyperlink behavior?

Comment: Since the # symbol is a wildcard in hyperlinks, a workaround doesn't really exist for this scenario other than NOT using a # in the folder names.  Only workaround I've ever seen was for a # sign in an Excel filename.  Major bug in Office IMO.