# Insert Hyperlink in word to an excel file that will open read-only when clicked?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-word-2010, hyperlink, read-only

To manually open an excel file as read-only I usually use excel /r "filename" on the command line, or just click file, open, open as read only from excel.

If I insert a hyperlink to an excel file in word, then clicking on it opens the excel file.

Is there anyway to insert a modified hyperlink in word that, when clicking it, would open the excel document as read-only?

Comment: Are you familiar with VBA at all? This can be accomplished with a VBA macro, but I'm not sure it can be just with a modified hyperlink.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Excel (2010) HYPERLINK: how to call a file with command line arguments and spaces in the path?](http://superuser.com/questions/492765/excel-2010-hyperlink-how-to-call-a-file-with-command-line-arguments-and-space)

Comment: @BenSampica I am familiar with VBA though only really with Excel.Not sure how to implement something like this is Word.

Answer (score 1):

Why not create a simple .cmd file and then hyperlink to it?

I just tested this:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office15\excel.exe" /r "c:\users\7651\Downloads\book3.xlsx